# Python Selenium get image title

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, attributes, element

I try to extract the image title of an element located by xpath:

```
<div class="c-label"><img title="title of the image" src="https://test.com/images/12345.png" class="c-label__image"> <span title="something" class="c-label__text">something</span></div>
```

with this code I get the div class (`c-label`) of the element:

```
xp = "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div"

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp)

content = element.get_attribute("class")

print(content)
```

now I want to get the img title, but `get_attribute("title")` or `get_attribute("img title")` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to target the `image` element to get the title.
Use below `xpath` or `css selector`.

**XPATH:**

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='c-label']/img[@class='c-label__image']").get_attribute("title"))
```

**CSS selector:**

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.c-label > img.c-label__image").get_attribute("title"))
```